# Python: How to solve the PDFPageCountError?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I have an OCR program that has worked normally so far. But now I got this error message for some folders where I wanted to read the PDF files:

PDFPageCountError: Unable to get page count.
Syntax Warning: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table

Can someone tell me what is the cause and how can I fix this error please? I also have to say that I get this error message with every folder now. I don't think that all PDF files are corrupted

```
path = r "D:\Users\Folder\example\...\2_ZWB" #path to folder with files
os.chdir(path)
os.getcwd()
foundfiles = os.listdir(path)
i = 0
 
counterDocuments = 0
numberoffoundPDFs = 0
for n in foundfiles:
    if FoundFiles[counterDocuments].endswith(".pdf"):
        NumberFoundPDFs = NumberFoundPDFs+1
    counterDocuments = counterDocuments+1
print("Number of found PDF documents: ",NumberFoundPDFs)
 
counterDocuments = 0
numberScannedPDFs = 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there also a method where such PDF files can be fixed in the code?

Comment: Skipping the fails seems to be a good approach. Can you possibly tell me how to include such a function in the code?

Comment: I also have to say that I get this error message with every folder now. I don't think that all PDF files are corrupted

Comment: It seems that there are missing code in the example above to sufficient help. Could be your script that corrupts the .pdf files after going thru them, thus getting error on every folder now?